# Python, Why is my variable implicitly becoming false for nested directories?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os

class TreeGenerator:
    def __init__(self, line_prefix = '|-- ', last_levels_line_prefix = '`-- ', object_prefix = '|   '):
        self.line_prefix = line_prefix
        self.last_levels_line_prefix = last_levels_line_prefix
        self.object_prefix = object_prefix
        self.base_spaces = ' ' * len(self.line_prefix)

    def generate(self, path, indent='', print_tree=False):
        if os.path.exists(path):
            tree = ''
            items = sorted(os.listdir(path))
            for index, item in enumerate(items):
                full_item_path = os.path.join(path, item)
                is_last = index == len(items) - 1
                line_prefix = self.last_levels_line_prefix if is_last else self.line_prefix
                object_prefix = self.object_prefix if not is_last else ' ' * len(self.line_prefix)

                treeline = f'{indent}{line_prefix}{item}'
                tree += treeline + '\n'

                if print_tree:
                    print(treeline)
                else:
                    print('here')

                if os.path.isdir(full_item_path):
                    next_indent = f'{indent}{object_prefix}'
                    self.generate(full_item_path, indent=next_indent)
        else:
            raise FileNotFoundError(f"No such file or directory found '{path}'")
            
            
            
tg = TreeGenerator()
tree = tg.generate('./test', print_tree=True)
```

Output:

```
|-- deps.edn
|-- resources
here
|-- src
here
here
here
`-- test
here
here
here
here
here
```

But, it will work without the `if` statement:

```
import os

class TreeGenerator:
    def __init__(self, line_prefix = '|-- ', last_levels_line_prefix = '`-- ', object_prefix = '|   '):
        self.line_prefix = line_prefix
        self.last_levels_line_prefix = last_levels_line_prefix
        self.object_prefix = object_prefix
        self.base_spaces = ' ' * len(self.line_prefix)

    def generate(self, path, indent='', print_tree=False):
        if os.path.exists(path):
            tree = ''
            items = sorted(os.listdir(path))
            for index, item in enumerate(items):
                full_item_path = os.path.join(path, item)
                is_last = index == len(items) - 1
                line_prefix = self.last_levels_line_prefix if is_last else self.line_prefix
                object_prefix = self.object_prefix if not is_last else ' ' * len(self.line_prefix)

                treeline = f'{indent}{line_prefix}{item}'
                tree += treeline + '\n'

                print(treeline)

                if os.path.isdir(full_item_path):
                    next_indent = f'{indent}{object_prefix}'
                    self.generate(full_item_path, indent=next_indent)
        else:
            raise FileNotFoundError(f"No such file or directory found '{path}'")
            
            
            
tg = TreeGenerator()
tree = tg.generate('./test', print_tree=True)
```

Output:

```
|-- deps.edn
|-- resources
|   `-- metabase-plugin.yaml
|-- src
|   `-- metabase
|       `-- driver
|           `-- sqlite.clj
`-- test
    `-- metabase
        |-- driver
        |   `-- sqlite_test.clj
        `-- test
            `-- sqlite.clj
```

Comment: I'm glad you got an answer. For future reference, [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some great debugging tips that will help you track down things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your recursive call is not passing along its value of `print_tree`, so the nested calls will always be `False`.

Comment: You are correct, silly me. I will accept your answer. Stackoverflow is currently making me wait 2 minutes.